# Relative imports across root directories in Jest

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

The [`rootDirs`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#rootDirs) element of a [`tsconfig.json`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig) file merges multiple physical directories into a single virtual directory.

This works for relative imports, so with the following file / folder structure

- `src/`

  - `main/`

    - `file.ts`
  - `test/`

    - `file.test.ts`

and the following [`tsconfig.json`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig)

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "rootDirs": [
            "src/main",
            "src/test"
        ],
        "moduleResolution": "node"
    }
}
```

and with the following import in `file.test.ts`

```
import { something } from "./file"
```

the import will find `file.ts`.

If I run `file.test.ts` in Jest, however, it fails with the following error

```
Cannot find module './file' from 'test/file.test.ts'
```

Does Jest / ts-jest support something similar to the Typescript [`rootDirs`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#rootDirs) element ? I tried the [`roots`](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#roots-arraystring) element, but it did not fix the issue.